# Очистка переменных в PHP

Tags: память, php

Уже был похожий вопрос, но там не было ответа на то, что меня интересует.

- Зачем это делается, если сборщик мусора все равно все уберет?
- Насколько я помню есть целый механизм по освобождению памяти, который убивает процессы (например FastCGI) и вновь запускает их. Вроде бы если этого не делать, то память переполняется. Является ли очистка переменных способом уменьшить количество перезапусков воркеров?
- Дает ли это какой то бонус в производительности? (дополнение ко 2му вопросу) или же использование этого механизма работает быстрее ручной очистки?
- В плане безопасности, имеет ли смысл очищать переменную сразу после отпадания необходимости в ней?
- Что становится с переменной после unset? Получается ли что isset будет возвращать false?

Вроде бы пока все, если появятся новые вопросы - добавлю в список.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Зачем это делается, если сборщик мусора все равно все уберет?

Вообще говоря используется редко. Сам не помню когда в последний раз применял. Ну разве что для массивов - для удаления элементов

> Является ли очистка переменных способом уменьшить количество перезапусков воркеров?

Нет. В режиме FastCGI интерпретатор каждый раз инициализируется заново, так что не стоит тут вообще заморачиваться.

> В плане безопасности, имеет ли смысл очищать переменную сразу после отпадания необходимости в ней?

Честно говоря не понимаю причем тут безопасность

> Что становится с переменной после unset? Получается ли что isset будет возвращать false?

Да

Comment: FastCGI я привел как пример, я точно не помню относительно чего я слышал об этом механизме. Возможно это касалось php как модуль apache и тогда соответственно это о воркерах apache. По поводу безопасности - например найден способ вывести некую переменную в центре скрипта, а ее можно было очистить перед этим куском. Это тоже пример.

Comment: > например найден способ вывести некую переменную в центре скрипта

А что за способ такой?

Comment: Например инъекция.

Comment: От инъекции unset никак не поможет. SQL-запрос как-никак выполнять надо :)

Comment: Есть понятие php-инъекция. То что ее допустить может только безголовый быдлокодер сейчас речь не идет)